# Objective c iPhone microphone self adjusts after loud noise

Tags: objective-c, iphone, microphone, avaudiorecorder

I'm using AVAudioRecorder and calling averagePowerForChannel.  When I start the app, the ambient noise, produces and a decibel value of, for example, -50.  However, if the iPhone is exposed to sustained loud noise that value looks to automatically adjust.  So, for example, if I blow into the microphone, then let it return to ambient noise level, the decibel value is now, for example, -90.

This does not happen on my iPhone 8.  However, this is occurring on my iPhone 12 Pro Max.

Is there a way that this can be disabled?

Comment: Maybe set it to measurement mode? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/mode/1616608-measurement

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did try that and I still observed the same behavior.